# How the device storage is encrypted with WSO2 EMM?

Tags: encryption, wso2, storage, scrypt, wso2-iot

The documentation tells how the transport layer is secured. But the only information about the device storage encryption is just that "it's encrypted".

Example for Android
 [Resource Definition to Encrypt Storage on Android Devices](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Resource+Definition+to+Encrypt+Storage+on+Android+Devices)

I guess it uses the Android's default encryption. Am I wrong?

If I'm right, is it possible to use another type of encryption/container? Such as veracrypt and similars...

Any clue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is done through the Android default as you mentioned. Have a look at the encryptStorage method found here[1] line number 685. There are no extension points provided here to plugin a new encryption mechanism.

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/services/Operation.java